# How can I read a byte in a serial buffer, delete it, and move on to the next byte?

Tags: python

I'm writing some code in python to read bytes from a serial port, and I need to find a specific byte from the buffer. Currently my code is this:

```py
import serial
i=0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/AMA0', baudrate=1000000)

def findStart():
    print(ser.read(i))
    if ser.read == 0x5A:
        print('Start byte found')
        i=0
    else:
        i = i+1
        print("Checking next byte")
        findStart()
findStart()
```

this doesn't do what I want it to do, as I would like it to read a byte, then go to the next one, rather than reading a then reading a and b then reading a and b and c as this currently does. I would also like to delete the byte after it has been read to prevent the buffer from becoming clogged with unnecessary bytes, can anyone recommend how to do these things?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine. `ser.read(n)` returns n bytes off of the serial buffer in a bytes object. The bytes are removed as they are read. So you don't need to increment an index. You can read 1 byte at a time with `ser.read()` or `ser.read(1)`. You can also read all of the bytes in the serial buffer using `ser.read(ser.Inwaiting())` as suggested by MarcosG.

Because you get a bytes object back from a read, it's easier to compare to a literal byte (`b'\x5a'`) than trying to compare to a hex value (`0x5a`). If you wanted to convert a byte to a value, try `ord(inbyte)`.

Here is an updated  version of your code. To avoid serial timeouts I've placed your main code in and endless loop and added `if serial.inWaiting()` statement:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/AMA0', baudrate=1000000)

def findStart():
    inbyte = ser.read(1)
    print(inbyte)
    if inbyte == b'\x5A':
        print('Start byte found')
    else:
        print("Start byte not found")


while True:    # endless loop
    if serial.inWaiting():
        findStart()
```

If you're confident that you will have something in your serial buffer when you run the script, you can replace the last three lines with

```
while serial.inWaiting():
    findStart()
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, a cautionary note on non-standard baudrates: are you sure you want to use that? I don't think it's a good idea...

Next: bytes are removed from the buffer as soon as you read them, so when you do `serial.read()` 1 byte is taken from the RX buffer and it won't be there anymore. Conclusion: your code is flawed.

In my opinion, it makes more sense not to mess with the buffer, read everything that gets there and process it on your code:

```
while True:
    if serial.inWaiting() != 0:
        data_read = serial.read(serial.inWaiting())     # read and empty buffer
        index = data_read.find(b'\x05')                 # Was there a 0x05?
        if index != -1:                                 # 0x05 was read
            if index == 0:                              # 0x05 was the first byte
                if len(data_read) == bytes_you_need:
                    # You got your frame
                else:
                    # Not quite: reorder based on index position
                ...
```

Comment: unfortunately the device I'm talking to was made by someone else and they coded that baudrate so no dice there. The answer is very helpful though, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use i as argument of findStart, `def findStart(i):` or if you really want to use a global, you should write :

```
import serial
i=0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/AMA0', baudrate=1000000)

def findStart():
    global i
    print(ser.read(i))
    if ser.read == 0x5A:
        print('Start byte found')
        i=0
    else:
        i = i+1
        print("Checking next byte")
        findStart()
findStart()
```